# Embedding external SVG in HTML for JavaScript manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a SVG image, showing geographical regions. 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Nederland_gemeenten_2009.svg

I want to display the SVG image on a webpage, and using a combination of JavaScript and CSS to interact with the image. (ie, detect clicks on a region, setting a different background color for a region).

I know this question is asked several times on StackOverflow, but I cannot find a complete code sample to work on further. Any recommendations on JavaScript packages, like jQuery, or plug-ins are welcome.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

My understanding of the question is that there are different aspects to be solved:

1. How to prepare the image for interaction
2. How to embed the image in the page
3. How to use CSS with SVG
4. How to use JavaScript for interaction

**Preparing the image**

First of all, I'd recommend to clean up the image. Inkscape leaves all kind of stuff there that you don't need, which includes elements and attributes in the `sodipodi:` and `inkscape:` namespaces as well as repetitive and/or redundant style attributes. You don't *have* to remove that, but it saves you some bandwidth/loading time, and if you want to work with CSS stylesheets, than the style attributes are in your way.

In your example file, you have 472 times the same style attribute. Remove all of them and create an equivalent CSS rule once.

You might also add some info about the municipalities to the markup. You could e.g. change the IDs of each path representing a municipality according to its name. You could also use a `data-*` attribute for this purpose. The latter has the advantage that you can use spaces. See below for how this is useful for interaction, especially with CSS.

**Embedding the image**

I'd recommend using the SVG inline, especially if you want to interact with CSS/JavaScript. This means, you just add the SVG markup to your HTML, or you load and insert it using Ajax. The latter has the benefit that the surrounding page loads faster and feels more responsive.

An example of an inline SVG element:

```
<div id="svgContainer">
  <!-- This is an HTML div, and inside goes the SVG -->
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="100px">
    <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

A simplified example of how to load SVG using Ajax:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","my.svg",false);
// Following line is just to be on the safe side;
// not needed if your server delivers SVG with correct MIME type
xhr.overrideMimeType("image/svg+xml");
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  // You might also want to check for xhr.readyState/xhr.status here
  document.getElementById("svgContainer")
    .appendChild(xhr.responseXML.documentElement);
};
xhr.send("");
```

**How to use CSS**

SVG can be styled just like HTML. Of course, SVG has it's own set of properties, like `fill-opacity` or `stroke-dasharray` and does not support a lot of HTML's properties, like `margin`, `position` or the like. But the selector mechanisms are 100% the same.

You can mix the CSS for your inline SVG with the CSS for your HTML, either inside a `<style>` element or an external CSS file. You can also use the `<style>` element inside the SVG code and `style` attributes.

Assuming you gave your SVG elements meaningful IDs or `data-*` attributes, two ways of highlighting municipalities using CSS would be:

```
#Bronckhorst, #Laarbeek {fill:red}
```

or

```
*[data-gemeente=Bronckhorst], *[data-gemeente=Laarbeek] {fill:red}
```

Or, of course, you can change the style attributes of the respective elements. Properties are also supported as attribute, i.e. `style="stroke-width:2"` can also be specified like `stroke-width="2"`. If the same property is set using both an attribute and CSS (either using the style attribute, a style element or an external stylesheet), the CSS overrides the attribute.

**JavaScript interaction**

There is basically no difference between HTML and SVG regarding JavaScript interaction, at least as long as you use plain vanilla DOM. This means, HTML specific features like `innerHTML` are not supported in SVG (i.e. there is no `innerSVG`). But SVG has its own graphics specific set of DOM methods ([see the W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/svgdom.html)).

One thing to be aware of is the work with namespaces. All SVG elements should be in the SVG namespace, and when creating them using JavaScript, `createElementNS()` has to be used instead of `createElement()`:

```
var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","use")
```

Likewise, attributes in the XLink namespace (namely `xlink:href`) have to be manipulated using `setAttributeNS()` instead of `setAttribute()`:

```
use.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","href","#foo")
```

As libraries like jQuery partly rely on HTML specific features, it's safer to avoid them when manipulating SVG. [**EDIT**: The situation might have improved since I wrote this answer. Not being a jQuery user, I don't know how well it works nowadays.] There are also SVG specific libraries like [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) which can be useful for specific purposes and are worth a look. (I'm doing D3.js injustice when simply calling it an SVG specific library, because it's more).

You can use `onclick` and similar attributes and standard DOM `addEventListener()`. A very simple example of using JavaScript events would be to add an event listener to the `<svg>` element that reports the name of a municipality that a user clicked on:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
  .addEventListener("click",function(evt){
    alert(evt.target.getAttribute("data-gemeente"))
  },
  false)
```

**Side note: Toopltips**
The same effect that you get using the `title` attribute in HTML can be achieved using the `<title>` element in SVG. Just put a `<title>` element inside an SVG element and on hover, you see a tooltip with the content of the `<title>` element.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="100px">
  <rect width="100" height="100">
    <title>test</title>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: All Code is untested. Please feel free to edit or report if you have corrections.

Comment: This is a really complete answer. I'd only add that it's better to avoid using jQuery in conjunction SVG, as it asumes all content is HTML and this will sometimes fail. IE9+ supports DOM 3's `addEventListener` which solves some of the major headaches of cross-browser development. Vanilla js often gets the job done, but if you want to abstract some of the DOM manipulation I'd recommend D3 http://d3js.org.

Comment: @Duopixel: Thanks, I added some info about libraries.

Comment: @Duopixel: Was that you with the bounty? Thank you very much, that is really generous.

Comment: just a little token of appreciation for an answer that I'll be coming back often :)

Comment: why `xhr.send("");` ?

Comment: see also http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/javascript/ which uses `<object>` tags

Answer (score 9):

Just for the record (knowing this comes a year late) I've found SnapSVG great for SVG manipulation. Same guy who was behind Raphaël:

http://snapsvg.io