# CSS namespace, SVG in HTML: Highlighting a state in an SVG file using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, maps

I have this file hosted on my site:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_US_Map.svg

If you look inside at the SVG, there are pretty good IDs that correspond to the state's 2 letter abbreviation.  That is, I go to inspect element, then URL, and see...

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="m 880.79902,142.42476 0.869,-1.0765 1.09022,-3.29102 -2.54308,-0.91347 -0.48499,-3.07156 -3.87985,-1.13162 -0.32332,-2.74824 -7.27475,-23.44082 -4.60142,-14.542988 -0.89708,-0.0051 -0.64664,1.616605 -0.64664,-0.484981 -0.96997,-0.969963 -1.45494,1.939925 -0.0485,5.032054 0.31165,5.667218 1.93992,2.74824 0,4.04152 -3.7182,5.06278 -2.58657,1.13164 0,1.13162 1.13163,1.77827 0,8.56802 -0.80831,9.21467 -0.16166,4.84982 0.96997,1.2933 -0.16166,4.52649 -0.48499,1.77828 0.96881,0.70922 16.78767,-4.42455 2.17487,-0.60245 1.84357,-2.77333 3.60523,-1.61312 z" id="NH" class="state"/>
```

I'm not trying to do anything interactive---I'd just like to color some states differently depending on a calculation, as a choropleth.

If I had a list of 3 color groups, Red, Green, Gray, and each state was in those groups, how should I collect my CSS to color this map according to that?

I tried this pure CSS, which didn't work:

```
#MI, #NH, #ME, #AK { 
   fill: "#ff0000";
}

#HI, #FL, #NY {
   fill: "#00FF00";
}

#CA {
   fill: "#F1F1F1"
}
```

I understand that I am supposed to use the SVG standard "fill" attribute rather than the CSS attribute "background-color."

Here are my other efforts using CSS+javascript on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/7wRmX/2/

HTML:

```
<BODY>
    <h1>First try image</h1>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Blank_US_Map.svg" alt="Map of coverage across the US.">
<hr>
    <h1>Second try Object</h1>
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Blank_US_Map.svg">
  JUNK
</object>
<hr>    
    <h1>Third try Use</h1>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<use xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Blank_US_Map.svg"/>
</svg>
</BODY>
```

CSS:

```
.s5 {
    fill: #00FA19;
    color: #00FA19;
    background-color:#00FA19;
}

svg #NV {
    fill: #00FA19;
    color: #00FA19;
    background-color:#00FA19;    
}

hover {
  fill:red;
}

.state {
  fill: red;
}

path {
    fill: blue;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var element = document.getElementById("CA");
element.setAttribute("class", "s5");
```

None of these modifications actually produce any color.

I tried a couple more things here, including using javascript to add CSS, as well as just trying to grab the element by name.

My guess in all these misadventures is I am not scoping the ID correctly?  It needs to be told to look for the ID within the SVG or something?  Or that it's a `<path>` object within the SVG?

My other guess would be I'm hosting this improperly, and [the only way to style SVG is to use inline SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068031/embedding-external-svg-in-html-for-javascript-manipulation)?  If that is the case, I'd be looking for a way to load SVG using python flask.

Comment: Remove the quotes from your color literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the colour of an SVG file via CSS you need to [link that CSS within the file itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS) and not from the container, either by adding a `<style>` element in the SVG file, a `<?xml-stylesheet href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css"?>` line or a html `<link>` element to link to an external stylesheet.

You can do it externally using javascript if you're using an `<object>` tag but you won't be able to make external modifications to an `<image>` tag.

For an `<object>` tag you need to get the SVG document so if you have

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" id="obj" data="..."/>
```

you could access the contents by using

```
document.getElementById("obj").contentDocument.getElementById("CA");
element.setAttribute("class", "s5");
```

but s5 would still need to be a CSS class defined within the SVG document and not within your wrapper html document.

would do that for instance. You see how you go from the `<object>` to its contentDocument.

There's more detail on scripting [here](https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/scripting-across-object.html)